# Windows 8.1 Acer Aspire can't disable safe boot

Tags: windows-8.1

I am planning to dual boot a GNU/Linux distro with my windows 8 and for that I need to disable safe boot in the BIOS. When I go there though, I can't change the safe boot option. It's grayed out and I can't select it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R20aQ.jpg

How can I disable secure boot?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enable BIOS compatibility elsewhere in your setup before you can turn off Secure Boot.  It may be called Compatibility Support Module (CSM) or something similar.  It may also be a two-step process before you can finally disable it.

Comment: Is this option also available in the BIOS? I assume so.

Comment: Yes. That'd be where you have to configure it.  I don't remember if it was a Acer or an Asus laptop I ran across but disabling secure boot was annoyingly complicated, and that's what the answer wound up being.